# Regex that works on Athena does not work in spark-sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have a `regex` which works with `Athena` but not in `spark-sql`.
What should I change in `spark-sql` so I will get same output as in `Athena`?

```
Sample Input: 'ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV'
Expected output: ['ASEIAW,TPOIBV'] - An array with all matching elements which is an alphabet in upper case with exactly 6 charterers.
```

Athena execution:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' , '(\b[A-Z]{6}\b)+'), 'ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' as INPUT;
    
_col0              |INPUT                        |
-------------------+-----------------------------+
['ASEIAW','TPOIBV']|ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV|
```

SPARK SQL execution:

```
spark.sql("""SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' , '(\b[A-Z]{6}\b)+') as regex_out, 'ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' as INPUT""").show()
+---------+--------------------+
|regex_out|               INPUT|
+---------+--------------------+
|       []|ASEIAW,1245555,as...|
+---------+--------------------+
```

I want to see the same output in spark which I see in Athena. What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the `\` characters:

```
spark.sql("""SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' , '(\\\\b[A-Z]{6}\\\\b)+') as regex_out, 'ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' as INPUT""").show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work. You needed more `\`

```
spark.sql("""SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL('ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' , '(\\\\b[A-Z]{6}\\\\b)+') as regex_out, 'ASEIAW,1245555,asda2dd,TPOIBV' as INPUT""").show()
```